# Show posts when clicking on a tag (django)

Tags: django, tags

I am new to django and I am facing a problem I can't solve.

I'm making a blog and I want to be able to click on a tag and go to  a new page which will have all posts with this tag. I already made a page which has the selected tag as a slug in the url, but I don't know how to show all the posts with that tag on this page.
My models page:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tag_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    image_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

My urls page:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.starting_page, name = "starting-page"),
    path("posts", views.posts, name = "posts-page"),
    path("posts/<slug:slug>", views.post_detail, name = "posts-detail-page"),
    path("posts/tag/<slug:tags>", views.post_tag, name = "post-tag-page"), 
   
]
```

and the function I created to render this:

```
  def post_tag (request, tags):
        identified_tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, tag_slug=tags)
        return render (request, "blog/post-tags.html")
```

I use this function to render the page but I do't know how to select (and render) all posts (their images to be precise) which have a specific tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query all posts with specified tag and pass it to the template via context

```
def post_tag (request, tags):
    identified_tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, tag_slug=tags)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tag=identified_tag).all()
    return render(request, "blog/post-tags.html", {"posts": posts})
```

In your template you can access posts like this

```
{% for post in posts %}
  {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Alexdimirop I'm happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the posts with:

```
def post_tag (request, tags):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__tag_slug=tags)
    return render (request, 'blog/post-tags.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Here `posts` is a `QuerySet` with all the `Post`s that have a tag with as `tag_slug` the `tags` URL parameter.